# Either document.location or window.location.href won't work in the if part of the condition, but will work on the else part

Tags: javascript, url

I use the following code to validate a password in a form. If the password is correct - Move the user to site X. If it's incorrect (after 3 tries), move the user to site Y.

For some reason, it works only for site Y.

### My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        Enter password to continue: <br>
        <input type="text" id="user"/>
        <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enter site"/>
        </form>

        <script>
           let tries = 0;
                let error = 0;
            let password = 'tiesto';

            document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = ()=> {
                let passwordValue = document.querySelector('#user').value;
                if (password === passwordValue) {
                    window.location.href = 'http://maariv.co.il';
                } else {
                    tries++;
                    alert('Try again please.');
                }

                if (tries === 3) { // 3 is the border.
                    error++;
                }

                if (error === 1) {
                    window.location.href = 'http://microsoft.com';
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### I tried doing:

1. Checking for syntax errors all over the code.
2. Changing `===` to `==` (I thought, maybe due to it being a string, the quote marks counted as well, of course I was mistaken).
3. `window.location.href = 'http://maariv.co.il', true`;
4. Adding `return false` right under `window.location.href`

As a beginner I ask, why would the condition works only in a half? That is, the positive part (than) doesn't work but the negative part (else) does work.

### Update:

This is just an exercise. Indeed. This isn't going to production. In production I should store and request the password from a database.

Comment: But... this is too easy to hack. Just having a look at your code, and anybody on your site will know the password is "tiesto". Tell me this is just a test, and this code is not going to production.

Comment: This is just an exercise. Indeed. This isn't going to production. In production I should store and request the password from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return` :

```
if (password === passwordValue) {
    return window.location.href = 'http://maariv.co.il';
}
```

Otherwise, the function will execute to the end, and you will reach the second redirection, that will then override the first one.

Comment: It will only drop into the other redirect if you've had 3 bad tries.  Entering the correct password on the first or second attempt should still work

Comment: Indeed. Suggesting that returning from inside the first `if` won't make any difference, since it's not going to be going into the other `if`s in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line `let passwordValue = document.querySelector('#user').value;` inside onclick of "mybutton".

```js
let tries = 0;
let error = 0;
let password = 'tiesto';

document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = ()=> {

    let passwordInput = document.querySelector('#passwordInput').value;
    if (password === passwordValue) {
        window.location.href = 'http://maariv.co.il';
    } else {
        tries++;
        alert('Try again please.');
    }

    if (tries === 3) { // 3 is the border.
        error++;
    }

    if (error === 1) {
    window.location.href = 'http://microsoft.com';
    }
};
```

```html
<form>
  Enter password to continue: <br>
  <input type="text" id="user" />
  <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enter site" />
</form>
```

Comment: Good spot.  A bit more explanation of why this is necessary would make this an even better answer!

Comment: I don't see any onload function. So when the page loads the `passwordValue` will be blank and the same is used in button click. I moved the code below to onclick so that the input value is captured and validated upon button click.

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if I move it there, the exact same problem occur. Actually, the original code was like that...

Comment: I tested and it works in Chrome and Edge (not working in IE 11 as it complains about `() =>` (syntax error). Please verify from developer console on what the error message is and the value of `passwordValue` field.